# How to delay operation in android(why doesn't handler work?)

Tags: android, handler, delay

I made an animation(I named it slide.xml), my simple app includes a button, when user click the button the animation starts in an ImageView, I want to make the imageView invisible after the animation is finished. I searched internet and I found using handler is what one needs to make this possible.

this is what i tried:

```
import java.util.logging.Handler;
```

and for onClick method:

```
imageViewForGif = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewForGif);
    imageViewForGif.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slide);
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageViewForGif.getBackground();
    imageViewForGif.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    frameAnimation.start();

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            imageViewForGif.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

but compiler doesn't recognize `new Handler()` and `postDelayed`. 
I don't know what I have done wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this import statement:

```
import android.os.Handler;
```

instead of `import android.util.logging.Handler;`

What you are searching for is androids `Handler` which manages thread queues.
Java's logging handler is actually nothing you should worry about. From the documentation:

> **android**:
>   There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and runnables to be executed as some point in the future; and (2) to enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.
>
> ---
>
> **java:** A Handler object accepts a logging request and exports the desired messages to a target, for example, a file, the console, etc

Comment: Thank you, I pressed alt+enter and I thought Android Studio itself will import correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You have to import Handler from

```
import android.os.Handler;
```

instead of

```
import java.util.logging.Handler;
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try using this class:

```
import android.os.Handler;
```